# Cython with dict same as python

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I have tried a few available solutions but unable to get any speed-ups with the following Cython code.

The time taken by the cython code is same as its python equivalent.

#### calculate_sum.pyx

```
# key_id: it is a string
# values_dict: it is a dictionary with key as str and values as numpy.ndarray consisting of floats
# e.g.: print(values_dict['abc']) will give out numpy.ndarray([0.01, 1.01, 2.05]). values_dict has many such entries.

cpdef dict calculate_sum(str key_id, dict values_dict):
     cdef dict result_dict = {}
     cdef str check_id

     for check_id, values in values_dict.items():
           if check_id != key_id:
                result_dict[check_id] = sum(values)

     return result_dict
```

#### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('calculate_sum.pyx'))
```

#### main.py

```
import calculate_sum

# ...
# piece of code which computes values_dict
# ...

key_id = 'abc'
sum_value = calculate_sum.calculate_sum(key_id, values_dict)
```

Any suggestion(s)/help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking/profiling of your original program and the Cython version?

Comment: there was not much to benchmark. the python version was working better, so was wondering if there is a way to cythonize it

Comment: Forgot to ask: Are you doing this for educational purposes, or do you need to speed up an actual program?

Comment: Answer to both the questions is: Yes. Need to speed-up a code and if things work-out then would write a tutorial about do's-n-dont's.

Comment: Hmm well in the case can you share the rest of the program? Are you allowed to optimize the rest of it? As DavidW said, it’s unlikely that there is much to gain by using Cython on this small snippet.

Comment: Does your program have a lot of places with loops over arrays where you're indexing one element at a time? If "yes" then Cython is the right tool, if "no" then Cython probably isn't the right tool. (Sometimes it's worth unrolling Numpy array operations into loops in Cython, but usually where multiple operations can be combined together to avoid temporaries). There are tutorials on the internet about Cython and then mostly deal with Numpy and loops (because that's what it's good at)

Comment: @ Alexander Unfortunately, it will be too much to add for the rest of the code, that's why created a small snippet out of the original one. 
@ DavidW Thanks for the tip. Not many loops though but dict to play with. So am working on changing dict to array to loop over which could potentially give me speed-up using Cython.

Answer (score 1):

In general I don't think Cython will help with this code: it's mostly manipulating Python objects and the speedup from that tends to be small. Some suggestions:

- For a numpy array `x.sum()` is much faster than `sum(x)` (for a quick test-case on my PC about 60x faster). If you know the values will be Numpy arrays then do this directly.
- The code can be rewritten to use a dictionary comprehension. This might gain a little speed (mostly because it may be able to pre-allocate the right size).
- It might be worth omitting the `if` statement inside the loop, and calculating the sum for every key (then dropping `key_id` afterwards). Time this.

Combined:

```
def calculate_sum(key_id, values_dict):
    result_dict = { key: values.sum() for key, values in values_dict.items() }
    del result_dict[key_id]
    return result_dict
```

Note that I've dropped all the Cython stuff since I think it's pointless here. I don't have a huge interest in benchmarking this, but I suspect the change to `sum` will make the main difference.

---

An alternative you might want to look at is to use Pandas (code here is untested...). Assuming you've created a `values` DataFrame with `values = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values_dict)` then:

```
def calculate_sum(key_id, values):
    return values.sum(axis=1).drop(key_id)
```

This will work best of all the Numpy arrays are the same length (although I don't think it's an absolute requirement). You'd be aiming to use Pandas universally rather than frequently converting to and from `dict`. Again, Cython won't help here.

Comment: thanks, that definitely helps with speed-up. I have read dict are not the best when it comes to cython so was wondering if there is way. if I replace sum with norm or any other operation then do you think cython can help?

Comment: If you want something that acts like a `dict` then `dict` is the best option. For standard operations like norm you'd probably still be best just calling the Numpy function (in which case Cython wouldn't really help).

Comment: @CodeChannel See edit at the end for another suggestion of a data structure that might be better than `dict`

Comment: that's an interesting approach to look into. Will see how it works. But as far as I understand pandas would not provide the speed-up of Cython. I'll try to work around making dict to multi-dimensional array.

Comment: If necessary you can access the underlying Pandas data in Cython (since ultimately it's stored in `pd.DataFrame.values` is a numpy array). However, try it without first since lots of array operations are written in C anyway